# Where is this top space on top of my page coming from?

Tags: css

In this page: http://readtypechinese.com/

There is some sort of top margin. The body doesn't have any margin.padding. Nor does the html element. I checked the other elements but none seem to be producing it.

What could be the reason?

**Relevant HTML:**

```
<body class="home page page-id-189 page-template page-template-nonlogin-php single-author singular two-column right-sidebar">


  <div id="header">
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="logo"><a href="http://readtypechinese.com/" title="Read and Type Chinese Online" rel="home">Read and Type Chinese Online</a></h1>
      <ul class="navigation">
        <li>
```

Relevant head section:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 6]>
<html id="ie6" dir="ltr" lang="en-US" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>
<html id="ie7" dir="ltr" lang="en-US" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
<html id="ie8" dir="ltr" lang="en-US" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !(IE 6) | !(IE 7) | !(IE 8)  ]><!-->
<html dir="ltr" lang="en-US" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  <meta name="description" content="Lessons and tools that will help you learn how to read and type in Chinese." />
  <meta name="keywords" content="learn, read, type, chinese, mandarin, characters, hanzi, radicals" />
  <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
  <meta content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' name='viewport'>
  <title>Learn how to Read and Type in Chinese</title>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://readtypechinese.com/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
  <link rel="pingback" href="http://readtypechinese.com/xmlrpc.php" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://readtypechinese.com/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/style.css" />
```

**Relevant CSS:**

```
/* =Global
----------------------------------------------- */

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 960px;
}

/* =Structure
----------------------------------------------- */

#header h1,
#header-fixed h1,
#header-mobile h1,
.button,
.large-bg h3,
.content-front.content-front-right img,
.content-front.content-front-left .details {
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.zopim {
  display: none;
}

/* =Header
----------------------------------------------- */
#header-mobile {
  display: none;
}

#header {
  background: #FFF;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #111; 
  height: 98px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 0 0 4px;
  -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 0 0 4px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 0 0 4px;
}

#header h1 {
  background: url(images/logo.png) no-repeat 0 0;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 60px 0 0;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  width: 159px;
  height: 85px;
}

#header h1 a {
  float: left;
  width: 159px;
  height: 85px;
}

#header .tagline {
  color: #FFF;
  float: left;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: Aller Regular, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  margin: 38px 0 0;
  text-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 -2px 0;
}

#header-fixed {
  background: #FFF;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #111;
  position: fixed;
  top: -70px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 0 0 4px;
  -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 0 0 4px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 0 0 4px;
}

#header-fixed .tagline {
  color: #FFF;
  float: left;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-family: Aller Regular, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  margin: 24px 0 0;
  text-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 -2px 0;
}

#header .navigation {
  float: right;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 22px 0 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 302px;
}

#header .navigation li {
  float: left;
}

#header .navigation li a {
  border-right: 1px solid #BBB;
  color: #BBB;
  float: left;
  padding: 0 20px;
  width: 60px;
  text-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 -1px 0;
}

#header .navigation li a.contact {
  border-width: 0;
  color: #FFF;
}

#header .navigation li a:hover {
  color: #dd3921;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#header .navigation li a img {
  margin: 0 0 2px;
}

#header .navigation li a span {
  width: 20px;
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "there is some sort of top margin". Which element does this appear on? The website is filled with broken images. It's impossible to tell what you're talking about. Even your `body` has a `header` div. This makes my head hurt.

Comment: This page's code contains a number of errors.  A HTML validator could help you find and repair them.

Answer (score 3):

It's coming from line 836 of `http://readtypechinese.com/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/style.css` - the height of `.large-bg-1` is 294px.

Screen shots:

---

**Before deleting line 836**:

[image]

---

**After deleting line 836**:

[image]

---

Comment: I don't think that is the space OP is referring to

Comment: Really? If that's the case, my bad... :/

Answer (score 2):

It is coming from this "space" being generated by your code http://d.pr/i/bWlo which if you encode it for a URL you will see that it is `%0a` (new-line) character.

Deleting it removes the space http://d.pr/i/zqea

However, I am not sure what you are using to generate the source since you haven't given any information about that.